# Swift ui Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am having the following problem when used in `init()`, can anyone help me out?

[image]

```swift
    @State private var activity: [ResponseActivity] = [ResponseActivity()]

    func getActivity(completion: @escaping ([ResponseActivity]?) -> ()){
        var userInfo: [ResponseActivity] = [ResponseActivity()]
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/\(self.userInfo.login)/received_events")!
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        print("self.userInfo.login", self.userInfo.login)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, urlResponse, error in
            guard let content = data else {
                print("Error getting data from API.")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                userInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode([ResponseActivity].self, from: content)
            } catch {
                print("Error parsing URL from data Activity.")
                return
            }
            completion(userInfo)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Properties in a `struct` like this (`View`) are immutable. You can set initial values inside `init`, but then they aren't mutable later. Special property wrappers like `@State` let you mutate values later on, but you're attempting to set the actual value on the `struct` by using `_activity = State(...)`.

I'd suggest moving asynchronous code like this to an `ObservableObject` -- then, you'll have a `class` with mutable properties. This will mean that your `userInfo`, `isLogin`, etc will be `@Published` properties and will probably need to be optionals, since they won't have values until `getActivity` completes.

Comment: If I post the code, can I ask you to show me how would you do it?

Comment: I've already explained how to do it -- can you post your attempt as an edit to the question so I know where you're having trouble?

Comment: I tried as you indicated, I edited the post, but I'm having problems.
Can I ask you where am I wrong?

Comment: I answered your initial question — what you’ve run into now are completely different questions and don’t fall under the scope of the original issue (mutating self in a strict). In general on SO, the etiquette is to create a new question in this situation. When I asked you to edit, I assumed you were having issues with my suggestions, which this is beyond. The main problem I see is that you aren’t using the same instance of StateApp between the menu and footer. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I will modify this and open a new question.

Comment: @Paul If this answered the initial question, you can mark it as correct with the green checkmark.